# Posso ter menus com vários níveis (+3) no Web2py

Tags: submenu, web2py

Amigos,
Estou tentando criar um menu em uma aplicação web2py com uma estrutura parecida com:

- Menu 0

  - Menu 1

    - Item A
    - Item B
    - Menu 2

      - Item C

É possível ?
Tentei partir do código da aplicação welcome, mas não funcionou.
Grato pela ajuda.